# Animation using Runnable?

Tags: android, animation, handler, runnable

I'm trying to animate an ImageView using `Runnable` and `Handler.postDelayed`. Bitmap operations all work fine but instead of the animation I get the final result of the ImageView. What is wrong in here?

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.clock_flip_top);
    final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        float c = i/5;

        src = new float[] { 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 0,
                    bitmap.getHeight() };
        dst = new float[] { 0 - c, 0, bitmap.getWidth() + c, 0,
                bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 0,
                bitmap.getHeight() };

        anim = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                matrix.setPolyToPoly(src, 0, dst, 0, src.length >> 1);
                Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap
                        .createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                                bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
                handler.postDelayed(anim, i * 200);

            }

        };
        anim.run();
    }
```

Comment: I don't get it, why are you implementing Runnable? Did you want a separate thread for your animation? If so, have a loop on your run and call it once.

Comment: The loop would be too fast for the animation to show properly, Runnable lets me repeat the bitmap transformation `i` times to have a running animation. Also this is a perspective animation, for which I couldn't find a normal `Animation` method.

Answer (score 0):

You do not call `run()`. To have your Runnable object run in another thread you must create a Thread object passing it your Runnable object in the constructor to Thread object. You then call `start()` on the thread object. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html) for detailed description of how to start threads.

Comment: I do call `run()` at the end of the loop.

Comment: No you NEVER call run(). The run() method is for use by the Thread object and you start the Thread by a call to its start() method. Read the link I gave in my answer about threads and how to use them in Java.